# ViewSet class variable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-viewsets

Now I have the following logic implemented for a `GET` request in `Django Rest Framework`:

```
class SomeViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                  GenericViewSet):
    count = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        query_set = ... # some_logic
        self.count = query_set.count()
        return query_set

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
        response.data = {'count': self.count,
                         'data': response.data}
        return response
```

That is, the `queryset` is calculated according to complex logic, and it may contain a different number of objects that need to be returned in a `GET` request, since I don’t have access to the `query_set` variable inside the list function and I don’t want to copy the `query_set` calculation logic, I decided do it with a class variable.

But still, the feeling that this is not very correct does not leave. What other options are there?

Comment: What should be returned in case you paginate? The number of items on the "page" or the total number of elements?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem total number of elements in the `query_set` variable, regardless of pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `self.get_queryset()` inside the list method instead of using a class variable. The `get_queryset` method will be executed every time you call it, and it will return the current queryset so:

```py
class SomeViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                  GenericViewSet):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ... # some_logic

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        response = super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
        response.data = {'count': queryset.count(),
                         'data': response.data}
        return response
```

### Edit:

To avoid the issue of multiple database queries, you can make use of the queryset that is already retrieved by the `ListModelMixin` and stored in the `response.data` attribute so:

```py
class SomeViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                  GenericViewSet):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ... # some_logic

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
        queryset = response.data
        response.data = {'count': len(queryset),
                         'data': queryset}
        return response
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Wouldn't this be a double query to the database, because the `list` method in the `ListModelMixin` also calls the `get_query_set` function?

Comment: @Анонимныйволшебник Yes, calling `self.get_queryset()` in the list method and in the ListModelMixin could result in multiple database queries.

Comment: Sorry, can i ask you? Any suggestion if i return slice in `get_query_set` but need to get the full length (in `list`) before i slice? If you help i can upvote your other answer